# Why doesn't this picture show up?

Tags: html, css, image, safari

This picture never shows up in Safari for Mac & Windows or Chrome for Mac.  Even after giving it an inline style of `display:block !important;` Chrome changes it to `display:none;` and Safari seems to be doing the same and changing the `visibility:hidden;` and `opacity:0;`

It seems to work fine in all other browsers.  Can you give me an idea as to why this may be happening in these browsers?

```
<img src="<? echo $_SESSION['ad']; ?>" style="max-width:100%;display:block !important;"/>
```

Comment: This may be because of an AdBlocker. What’s the actual file name and file path of the picture? Anyways, try to change anything in the file name that looks like “ad”, “advertisment”, etc.

Comment: Definitely sounds like an ad blocker causing you this head ache. Try changing the session ID to site-ad or anything other than just ad

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the website you are looking into might be a `Responsive Web Design`(RWD). Usually, in RWD a separate `CSS` will be defined specifically for each browser. And the browser specific styling is sometimes unable to override with your html img tag.

I suggest to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or some code inspect tools and try to know if that img tag has any browser specific styling. If you have permissions to edit that file, go and modify it.

I think this might work.